# request tracker 4 running standalone and number of child processes

Tags: process, request-tracker

I'm running request tracker 4 standalone, which means with not any http server in front.

My problem is that once I launch the server as in:

/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/request-tracker4/libexec/rt-server --port 80

Suddenly it creates a bunch of child processes which are consuming too much memory and systems starts to swaps.

beside the parent process it starts 10 child processes.

Is there any way to configure it to limit the max number of child processes.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just running it for development or maybe evaluation, try:

```
rt-server --server Standalone --port 80
```

That should run just one server.

If you want to set some other number of servers, you'd need to modify the rt-server script and pass --max-workers to Starlet (the default standalone server).

Comment: No need to modify the rt-server script, you can just add --max-workers=N to the command line quoted in the question.